Mixture of Models: A Simple Recipe for a ... Hangover?
I am reading Piterbarg's paper "Mixture of Models: A Simple Recipe for a ... Hangover?" (SSRN Link) and found myself confused about the example provided.
To use a mixture model to price path-dependent products, one must specify the mixture model dynamics, particularly how probabilities (weights) of different volatility scenarios evolve over time. This is done in the lognormal mixture model (Brigo and Mercurio), where the risk-neutral density of the asset is a mixture of lognormal densities, and an analytical diffusion coefficient is specified. The square of the local volatility $\nu(t,y)$ is a weighted average of the squared basic volatilities $\sigma_1^2(t), \dots, \sigma_N^2(t)$, with weights as functions of the marginal lognormal densities:
$$
\nu^2(t, y) = \sum_{i=1}^N \Lambda_i(t, y) \sigma_i^2(t) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i \sigma_i^2 p_i(S)}{\sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i p_i(S)}.
$$
However, in the example provided, the probabilities (weights) of the volatility scenarios remain constant over time. This static approach, where the value of the derivative in the mixture model is given by:
$$
V_{\text{MM}} = \sum_{i=1}^N p_i V(S_i),
$$
is unsuitable for valuing path-dependent derivatives, as it does not account for how volatility uncertainty evolves. While this works for simple contracts like European options (depending only on the terminal distribution), it fails for contracts requiring an understanding of underlying market dynamics.
For instance, the example considers a compound option. Using the mixture model, its value is computed as:
$$
V_{\text{MM}}(0, S_0) = p_1 E_1 \left[ \max \left( K_1 - S_{T_1}, E_1^{T_1} \left[ (K_2 - S_{T_2})^+ \right] \right) \right] 
+ p_2 E_2 \left[ \max \left( K_1 - S_{T_1}, E_2^{T_1} \left[ (K_2 - S_{T_2})^+ \right] \right) \right].
$$
At $T_1$, the compound option value is:
$$
V_{\text{MM}}(T_1, S) = \mathbb{1}_{\{S > S^*\}} H(S) + \mathbb{1}_{\{S \leq S^*\}} (K_1 - S),
$$
$$
H(S) = p_1 E_1^{T_1} \left[ (K_2 - S_{T_2})^+ \mid S_{T_1} = S \right] 
+ p_2 E_2^{T_1} \left[ (K_2 - S_{T_2})^+ \mid S_{T_1} = S \right].
$$
Alternatively, the continuation value approach gives:
$$
\tilde{V}_{\text{MM}}(0, S_0) = p_1 E_1 \left[ V_{\text{MM}}(T_1, S_{T_1}) \right] + 
p_2 E_2 \left[ V_{\text{MM}}(T_1, S_{T_1}) \right].
$$
However, these two valuations are inconsistent:
$$
V_{\text{MM}}(0, S_0) \neq \tilde{V}_{\text{MM}}(0, S_0).
$$
This inconsistency arises because the mixture model fails to account for the dynamics of volatility uncertainty. Can someone clarify the differences between these valuations and confirm whether my understanding of the paper is correct?

You have highlighted the very pivotal problem that was evident in Piterbarg's example: the static mixture model simply cannot capture path-dependent stuff due to fixed weights. I will elaborate on why the direct and continuation valuations differ.
The direct valuation, $V_{MM}$, is literally a weighted average of option values computed under various, fixed, volatility assumptions. It's like saying "the world is either high vol or low vol, with these fixed probabilities." Fine for European options since all they care about is the terminal distribution. But the path-dependent options, such as the compound option of the example, do depend on the path between now and maturity.
The continuation value approach, $\tilde{V}_{MM}$ attempts to be a bit more clever. It says, "let's look at the value at $T_1$ and then discount it back." But there's the rub: its still using the same fixed weights when its computing the expected value at $T_1$ - it is still refusing to take account of how the probability of being in a particular volatility regime may have changed by $T_1$, depending on the path taken by the underlier -.
It is exactly in this that the inconsistency arises. $V_{MM}$ assumes the weights are fixed from time 0 all the way to the final maturity. $\\tilde{V}_{MM}$ tries to introduce some form of dynamical element since it looks at an intermediary time, but it is a pseudo-dynamic: it still relies on initial, fixed weights. So, it is as good as trying to drive the car with the steering stuck. You can move the car forward, but you cannot actually steer it.
So, you are correct. It's not just a question of different ways of doing the calculation, but it's really a question of the fundamental problem of using static weights for path-dependent problems. You want weights which evolve with the underlying price in order to capture the dynamics of volatility uncertainty. That is why models with time-dependent weights or regime-switching dynamics are necessary for these kinds of options.
